# How to remove liked pages that no longer exist?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

On Facebook, if liked some pages in past, now want to unlike(remove from likes list), when click the page, it shows the page isn't available.

[image]

[image]

When click the picture, it redirected to this page:

[image]

Maybe the page had been deleted. But why it also exists in someone's likes list? And how to remove the unavailable pages in the likes list?